# WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW issue

Tags: mfc

On Dialog based application, if you create a new dialog(tool window), and you press alt-tab, you can see the main dialog, and the tool window is missing( that is ok, is what a tool window is made to do).

On sdi/mdi applications if you open a tool window and press alt-tab, the application disappear from task bar(mainframe too). And that is my problem . I want my mainframe to  always appear on task bar when I press alt-tab, even if a tool window is opened.

Any idea is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Actually this suggests that something else is wrong. I'm not able to reproduce this on my end.

Comment: I created new projects, without making other modifications. What could be wrong?

Comment: Which version of VS do you use? 2010? Also, which Windows version ...

Comment: I forgot to specify: On Dialog based application,  Application Window = true.
But I can't make it work with SDI application.